# Aliasing fields in Apollo GraphQL Server

Tags: node.js, graphql, apollo, apollo-server

Aliasing is very handy and works great when aliasing a specific resolver. For instance:

```
{
  admins: users(type:"admin"){
    username
  }
  moderators: users(type:"moderators"){
    moderators
  }
}
```

I'm not sure how to handle aliasing of the fields themselves though. For example:

```
{
  site_stats {
    hits: sum(field: "hits")
    bounces: sum(field: "bounces")
  }
}
```

If the resolver returns any `sum` value, the same value is aliased to both `hits` and `bounces` (which makes sense, since only a single sum value could even be returned). If I make the resolver use the alias names as the field names when returning the results, `hits` and `bounces` both become `null`.

I could simply break those fields out into separate resolvers, but that complicates integration for the front end devs. We would also lose a ton of efficiency benefits, since I can aggregate all the data needed in a single query to our data source (we're using ElasticSearch).

Any help from you geniuses would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: reasons to use aliases instead of simple `{ site_stats(someFilter:"month") { hits, bounces } }` ?

Comment: It might not have been the best example, but the point is that `sum` would return a single value based on a calculation (adding together all the numbers in the identified field, for example).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Using aliases and single fields has very limited usability.**

You can use complex filters (input params), f.e. list of keys to be returned and their associated params, f.e.

```
[{name:"hits", range:"month"}, 
{name:"bounces", range:"year"}]
```

With query - expected structure

```
{
  stats {
    name
    sum
    average
  }
}
```

Required fields may vary, f.e. only `name` and `sum`.

You can return arrays of object f.e.

```
{ stats: [
  { name:"hits", 
    sum:12345, 
    average: 456 }
```

Aliases can be usable here to choose different data sets f.e. `name` and `sum` for `hits`, `bounces` additionally with `average`.

... more declarative?

PS. There is nothing that "complicates integration for the front end devs". Result is json, can be converted/transformed/adapted after fetching (clinet side) when needed.

Comment: The "complicates integration" comment was about how the front end of our app currently builds the queries, and this would mean a big change. Doesn't mean it wouldn't be worth it, of course. Just that it would ideally be avoided if possible.

I do think this would require the least invasive changes in our setup. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're putting all your logic inside the root-level resolver (`site_stats`) instead of providing a resolver for the `sum` field. In other words, if your resolvers look like this:

```
const resolvers = {
  Query: {
    site_stats: () => {
      ...
      return { sum: someValue }
    },
  },
}
```

you should instead do something like:

```
const resolvers = {
  Query: {
    site_stats: () => {
      return {} // empty object
    },
  },
  SiteStats: {
    sum: () => {
      ...
      return someValue
    },
  },
}
```

This way you're not passing down the value for sum from the parent and relying on the default resolver -- you're explicitly providing the value for `sum` inside its resolver. Since the `sum` resolver will be called separately for each alias with the arguments specific to that alias, each alias will resolve accordingly.

Comment: Thanks for this! Am I right in thinking this would mean the query would look something like `hits: SiteStats { sum }, bounces: SiteStats { sum }`? That means that we'd have to make multiple back end queries to our data source, right? One for each alias?

Comment: You could apply the alias to the root field, but you could also apply the alias to `sum` as shown in your original post. That said, applying the alias to the root would solve your problem without additional changes to your resolvers.

Comment: Whether doing that results in multiple queries to your data source depends entirely on your resolver code.